# VBA interacting with website

Tags: javascript, vba

I'm writing a VBA macro for Excel to extract and print some data from a website, the job is almost complete. However there's a expandable "link" from a javascript function which I need to expand in a lot of the pages but everything I've done failed so far.

The code for the function is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" id="show"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
function show(link, idTable, prefIdRows) {
  var image = link.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  image.src = (image.src.indexOf('/plus-p.gif') >= 0) ? 'images/minus-p.gif' : 'images/plus-p.gif';
  var table = document.getElementById(idTable);
  var elements = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (element.id.indexOf(prefIdRows, 0) == 0) {
      if (element.style.display == 'none') {
         element.style.display = '';
      } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The link code is:

```html
<a href="#" onClick="show(this, 'result','m0-'); return false;">
<img align="left" src="images/plus-p.gif" alt="Show" style="cursor:pointer;">
</a>
```

I've already tried getelements by tag, classname, call execscript and nothing seems to work (I scraped everything that didn't work, so I don't have any code to reveal what I'm doing wrong, my bad).

Is there an easy way to do this? I barely know any javascript so I might be trying the wrong element in this.

Comment: Please share VBA code you have, specify what data you need to scrape, and URL.

Comment: Any update on this?